# Do Galaxy Buds+ use a dual BT Stack?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt, samsung-galaxy

I'm getting the dreaded 133 error when using BluetoothDevice.connectGatt and understand that if your Bluetooth device uses a dual BT Stack that this can be an issue so my question is:

Do Galaxy Buds+ use a dual BT Stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the Galaxy buds+ support classic Bluetooth. You can find this at the listing page here:-

https://launchstudio.bluetooth.com/ListingDetails/98723

You may need to create a Bluetooth account to access the details found under "View ICS details" but if you can access that you'll see that a few classic profiles are supported including SDP and A2DP.